# How to use $app/navigation inside the vitest unit test

Tags: reactjs, svelte, vite, sveltekit, vitest

Getting this error in files where I am using $app/navigation:
`Error: Failed to resolve import "$app/navigation" from "src/utils/navigationUtils.js". Does the file exist?`.

Here is my setupTests.js file but now getting the same error in this file.

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { vi } from "vitest";
import * as navigation from "$app/navigation";


// Mock SvelteKit runtime module $app/navigation
vi.mock("$app/navigation", () => ({
  afterNavigate: () => {},
  beforeNavigate: () => {},
  disableScrollHandling: () => {},
  goto: () => Promise.resolve(),
  invalidate: () => Promise.resolve(),
  invalidateAll: () => Promise.resolve(),
  prefetch: () => Promise.resolve(),
  prefetchRoutes: () => Promise.resolve(),
}));
```

After this configration now getting:
`Error: Failed to resolve import "$app/navigation" from "setupTests.js". Does the file exist?`

I have tried to mock the `$app/navigation` module in setupTests.js file but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of the `$xxx` paths in sveltekit, e.g. `$env`, `$app`, `$lib`, you can create a `__mocks__/xxx` directory where you can put your navigation mocks to be returned, so something like `__mocks__/app` in your case.  You can then put a `navigation.ts` with your mock which will be loaded for each of your tests.   Then in your `vitest.config.ts` add

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      $app: path.resolve(__dirname, '__mocks__/app')
    }
}
```

This will allow you to import a version you contrive into your tests.